# Fixture objects and cleanup in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, bdd, scalatest, fixtures

I am trying to understand fixture objects in Scala for BDD testing from this [link](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures).

**get-fixture methods/fixture-context objects** - The link says these two ways of using fixtures are recommended only when there are no cleanups required.

> get-fixture methods - The extract method refactor helps you create a fresh instances of mutable fixture objects in each test that needs them, **but doesn't help you clean them up when you're done.**

> fixture-context objects - By placing fixture methods and fields into traits, you can easily give each test just the newly created fixtures it needs by mixing together traits. Use this technique when you need different combinations of mutable fixture objects in different tests, **and don't need to clean up after**.

Since get-fixture methods as well as fixture context objects anyway provide new instances of the test data, isn't cleanup of test data automatically taken care of? What does clean up mean in this respect? Is the reference to cleanup meant in terms of garbage collection or in terms of data in a fixture object mutated by one test affecting another test adversely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbadge collection is always done. Cleanup could means things like:

- closing an opened file
- closing any opened stream
- deleting a created file
- disconnecting from database
- basically any activity that ensures that some state was restored to a way if was before